# Keycloak : validating access_token using PHP

Tags: php, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

Assuming that I received token after managed to login through *openid-connect*

`http://xxxxxx/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token`

```
{
    "access_token": "xxxxxx",
    "expires_in": 600,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "xxxxxx",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "not-before-policy": xxxx,
    "session_state": "xxxxx",
    "scope": "email profile"
}
```

Is there any ways on how to decode the payload of the jwt tokens just like the https://jwt.io/ did , using PHP? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this library https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt.

Why do you want to decode the `access_token` though? Usually it's the `id_token` that gets decoded so that the client can verify the end-user's identity. The process of decoding requires the JWT to have its signature verified.

You can use the library I mentioned above. The steps are easy. You need:

1. The JWT
2. Secret Key/ Public Key
3. Algorithm used to encode the JWT

The following snippet is used to decode + verify a JWT. It uses HS256 so a secret key must be in the possession of the client:

```
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

If you want to decode a JWT without verifying its signature (**unsafe**), you can create a function that separates each of the JWT section: header, body, and signature, and `base64url decode` it. Like so:

```
// Pass in the JWT, and choose which section. header = 0; body = 1; signature = 2
public function decodeJWT($jwt, $section = 0) {

    $parts = explode(".", $jwt);
    return json_decode(base64url_decode($parts[$section]));
}
```

**EDIT** if you're decoding + verifying an `id_token` which uses assymetric algorithm e.g. RSA256, RSA384 etc, you need the public key. OpenID Connect defines a JWK Set endpoint (`/.well-known/jwks.json`), which lists the public keys in JWK format. You can hit that endpoint and save the response in an array. In order to find which public key was used, the JWK has a `kid` claim/ property. Which represents the `key id`, the identifier of the public key. You can decode your `id_token` and grab its header using :

```
$header = decodeJWT($id_token, 0);
```

Then you can pass the header to the function below to get the key that was used to encode the `id_token`. Parameter `$keys` holds the JWK Set response:

```
function getIdTokenKey($keys, $header) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if ($key->kty == 'RSA') {
            if (!isset($header->kid) || $key->kid == $header->kid) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }   
    
    throw new Exception("key not found");
}

$key = getIdTokenKey($keys, $header);
```

Finally call the `decode` function, assume it's using `RSA256`:

```
$decoded = JWT::decode($id_token, $key, array('RSA256'));
```

**Edit(2)** On another note it's the same process to decode any JWT, be it an access token, id token, or arbitrary data being passed to different entities in a server environment.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try the codes . The reason why I try to decode the access_token is because I am able to receive the user's info through the token. I know this might be unsafe way to validate the user but it took me longer time to understand the authentication flow, so I take a shortcut. Thanks again for your brief explanation. It makes me understand much better. :D

Comment: @HaizadAnnuar my pleasure. If this answer helped solve your problem it'd be much appreciated to mark it as accepted :)